# mounted drives on raspberry pi os lite bullseye are presently unwritable without superuser privilege

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, file-permissions, home-server, qbittorrent

i'm running a headless media server off of a raspberry pi in my home, but i am presently unable to write anything onto it via qbittorrent (using the qbittorrent-nox package to run via webui) after getting it to work without needing a terminal constantly running it by using a service created via [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-qbittorrent/) guide. when using qbittorrent in a terminal accompanied by sudo, it is able to write to the drive, but with several attempts at trying to change permissions of the mounted folder using `chmod` and `chown`, i have been unsuccessful. is there a way i could either:

1. make the service run as root

or

2. make the mounted folder writeable by everyone (previously used `chmod ugo+rwx` and similar, with no dice)

any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, the guide doesn’t tell us where you’re trying to save those files. Please provide that path. Please also provide the exact `chmod` and `chown` command lines (including the path) you tried, as well as the output of `mount`.

Comment: @DanielB i believed i used `chmod ugo+rwx media` (when in root, trying to modify the folder `/media` where my drive was mounted using the command `sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media`, and now as i look into the command history, never successfully executed a chown command, only attempts such as `chown ugo+rwx media`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `chown` nor `chmod` is expected to work on exfat or other Windows filesystems.

You should probably add:

```
-o uid=qbittorrent,gid=qbittorrent
```

to the `mount` command to change the ownerships. (I don't think the position matters at all but right after `mount` or right before `/dev/sdb1` are definitely fine.)

If you want to access the directories / files in the mount with your "main user" (e.g. `pi`) without resorting to `sudo` or alike, you *might* need to add appropriate [permission *mask* mount options](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/exfat-fuse/mount.exfat.8.en.html) to the command as well to change the (group) permissions (and have the user added to the `qbittorrent` group as your linked guide instructed).

---

To run the torrent program as root, you just need to remove the `User=` and `Group=` lines in the service, but as the guide mentioned, you don't want to do that because of security reasons.

Comment: i found something similar earlier and added `umask=000` which i believe solves the same thing as you put here, except with even more freedom towards all users as i read.

Comment: Yeah that's essentially the same thing as "ugo+rwx", I think.

Comment: before i tried to do 777, as i thought that was what allowed total freedom, but instead i suppose it meant total restriction, as not only could i not write to the drive, i could not enter the mount folder either.